# How to solve this error while creating chips in android?

Tags: android, android-chips

I want to display a chip in an edit text on the click of a button. Here's what I have tried:

**ChipsMultiAutoCompleteTextview.java**
(This class has its contructors & this method to set name to chip when the user clicks the button.)

```
    public void setChips(String chip_title) {

    if (!chip_title.equals("")) {
        SpannableStringBuilder ssb = new SpannableStringBuilder(getText());


        int x = 0;

        LayoutInflater lf = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(
                Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        TextView textView = (TextView) lf.inflate(R.layout.chips_edittext,
                null);

        textView.setText(chip_title); // set text

        int spec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
        textView.measure(spec, spec);
        textView.layout(0, 0, textView.getMeasuredWidth(),
                textView.getMeasuredHeight());

        Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap(textView.getWidth(),
                textView.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(b);
        canvas.translate(-textView.getScrollX(), -textView.getScrollY());

        textView.draw(canvas);
        textView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);

        Bitmap cacheBmp = textView.getDrawingCache();
        Bitmap viewBmp = cacheBmp.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);

        textView.destroyDrawingCache(); // destory drawable
        // create bitmap drawable for imagespan

        BitmapDrawable bmpDrawable = new BitmapDrawable(viewBmp);
        bmpDrawable.setBounds(0, 0, bmpDrawable.getIntrinsicWidth(),
                bmpDrawable.getIntrinsicHeight());

        Log.d("startx", "" + x);
        Log.d("end", "" + (x + chip_title.length()));

        // create and set imagespan
        ssb.setSpan(new ImageSpan(bmpDrawable), x, x + chip_title.length(),
                Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

        x = x + chip_title.length() + 1;
        setText(ssb);

        // move cursor to last
        setSelection(getText().length());

    }
}
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

ChipsMultiAutoCompleteTextview mu;

Button btn1, btn2, btn3;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mu = (ChipsMultiAutoCompleteTextview) findViewById(R.id.multiAutoCompleteTextView1);

    btn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.but1);

    btn1.setOnClickListener(this);

}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.but1:

        String str1 = btn1.getText().toString();

        Log.d("Button name", str1);

        ChipsMultiAutoCompleteTextview chip1 = new ChipsMultiAutoCompleteTextview(
                this);
        chip1.setChips(str1);
        break;

    }

}
```

}

The program should produce a chip in the edit text on clicking the button. However, I get this error. The logcat details are as follows:

```
04-12 10:34:01.730: E/AndroidRuntime(23041): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-12 10:34:01.730: E/AndroidRuntime(23041): java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: setSpan (0 ... 4) ends beyond length 0
04-12 10:34:01.730: E/AndroidRuntime(23041):    at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.checkRange(SpannableStringBuilder.java:1016)
04-12 10:34:01.730: E/AndroidRuntime(23041):    at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.setSpan(SpannableStringBuilder.java:592)
04-12 10:34:01.730: E/AndroidRuntime(23041):    at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.setSpan(SpannableStringBuilder.java:588)
04-12 10:34:01.730: E/AndroidRuntime(23041):    at com.androidchipps.ChipsMultiAutoCompleteTextview.setChips(ChipsMultiAutoCompleteTextview.java:109)
04-12 10:34:01.730: E/AndroidRuntime(23041):    at com.androidchipps.MainActivity.onClick(MainActivity.java:65)
```

Comment: Does [it](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8602039/4762282) can help you?

Comment: @Ircover I already checked that. The indexes are precise. ie. from 0 to 4 and then next  from 5 to 9 & so on.. Any other suggestions pls...

Comment: Hi @Nevermore, were you able to achieve showing chips in EditText ? I am trying to do same. Any clues on implementing our own code ? I tried to reuse klinker github library but it has lots of code and I have to modify it at many places so getting complicated. Looking for any simple alternative. Alos my question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34130997/customizing-klinker41-android-chips-library-to-handle-custom-data-other-than-em.

Comment: @cgr Hi, I did not complete the chips at that time. However, later we sorted it out.