# Chips UI for custom data in Android. (OR) Customizing klinker41/android-chips library to handle custom data (other than EMAIL and CONTACTS)

Tags: android, android-adapter, android-chips

I want to implement android chips with material look as designed in [material chips](https://www.google.com/design/spec/components/chips.html). The only library that has implemented them this way is https://github.com/klinker41/android-chips. But it handles only Email and Phone contacts. I have list of my own data that has to be searchable and should be shown in chips when selected as same way this library does.

Has anybody used https://github.com/klinker41/android-chips library to handle the data other than Email and Phone ? If so, any hints on how to tailor it to handle my data ? Any suggestions regarding this ?

**EDIT :**

Question in general is that how to implement Chips UI in Android to handle custom data ?.

Comment: any luck with this? I'm trying to do the same thing

Comment: Hi, I added answer for you. Not an answer really but something to start with. I need some time to add full answer..let me know if you have specific questions..I will try to help you.

Comment: Check out this answer. No need to use 3rd party libs. http://stackoverflow.com/a/41776777/2254969

Comment: How about images in it and attaching adapter to search for autocompletetextview ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I implemented chips using https://github.com/splitwise/TokenAutoComplete.  After enough research with available libraries, I felt this library is best for custom data.
[I will try to add code as soon as possible. I could add image also in the chip.]

This is how my chips looks:

[image]

Comment: Thanks this helped a lot :)

Comment: Does the library have the material design UI or you had to do it yourself ? If you had to do it, is it straightforward ?

Comment: I had to do with round shape drawble..it also means that you've control of what you want to show. It is not difficult or not so straight forward..2 days of work for me at least.

Comment: Could you post a code snippet, if it's not too difficult?